# Releasing Excel*32 process after operation complete

Tags: c#, excel, marshalling, comobject

Trying to figure out why my EXCEL*32 process remains in use until both the my application AND the excel file are closed. I must be missing something after creation, it's like the application is holding onto the EXCEL *32 resource after this code. Any suggestions to get it to 'let go' after it's export operation is completed?

Also, I do not want to close the newly created Excel sheet, I just want to release the resource being used in relation to my actual .net application.

```
Application xls = new Application();
xls.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1;

// Create our new excel application and add our workbooks/worksheets
Workbook Workbook = xls.Workbooks.Add();
Worksheet CrossoverPartsWorksheet = xls.Worksheets[1];

// Create our new excel application and add our workbooks/worksheets
Workbook Workbook = xls.Workbooks.Add();
Worksheet CrossoverPartsWorksheet = xls.Worksheets[1];

/////////////////////////////////////////
// < DO EXCEL EXPORT OPERATIONS HERE > //
/////////////////////////////////////////

// Release our resources.
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Workbook);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(CrossoverPartsWorksheet);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xls);
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects ?

Comment: Already looked at this one which is where I got the Marshal.ReleaseComObject part from.

Comment: This is just not the right way to do this.  Call GC.Collect() instead.  And read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130382/understanding-garbage-collection-in-net/17131389#17131389) to understand why that doesn't work when you put it at the end of the method.  Put it in the caller method instead.

Comment: I am able to avoid GC all together, which is ideal when it isn't actually required, per the accepted answer in which @Dmitry Martovoi has provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
Workbook Workbook = xls.Workbooks.Add();
```

CLR creates [RCW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe.aspx) (Runtime Callable Wrapper) objects not only for `Workbook`, but for Workbooks collection too(coz you need object that then will be used for `Add()` method). And if CLR creates RCW object and you do not keep reference - you can't finalize it.

So, the main rule:
**You should avoid double-dot-calling expressions**:

```
var workbooks = xls.Workbooks;
var workbook = workbooks.Add();

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks);
```

Comment: BOOM! This works, did not realize there was a RCW with that (Didn't even know what that was to be honest).

Answer (score 0):

`Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xls)` is what your looking for.

Comment: Still doesn't release in task manager until the .net application is closed. Hence, I create 3 different Excel exports and close all 3, all are still showing as running processes until I quit the application.

Comment: Not sure what your doing wrong then, I have tested this many times. Make sure you quit the app and dispose all excel objects with this method.

Comment: I think that's the problem, just in what you said there. I'm not wanting to quit anything. I want to leave the excel app open as well as the excel export app, just don't want the app to hold onto the resource. Am I making sense with that?